# GAE - Execute many small tasks after a fixed time

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, scheduled-tasks, task-queue

I'd like to make a Google App Engine app that sends a Facebook message to a user a fixed time (e.g. one day) after they click a button in the app.  It's not scalable to use [cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) or the [task queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) for potentially millions of tiny jobs.  I've also considered implementing my own queue using a [background thread](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/background_thread), but that's only available using the [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/) API as far as I know, which is designed for much larger usage and is not free.

Is there a scalable way for a free Google App Engine app to execute a large number of small tasks after a fixed period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, if you're looking to do millions of tiny jobs, you're going to blow past the free quota very quickly, any way you look at it.  The free quota's meant for testing.

It depends on the granularity of your tasks.  If you're executing a lot of tasks once per day, cron hooked up to a mapreduce operation (which essentially sends out a bunch of tasks on task queues) works fine.  You'll basically issue a datastore query to find the tasks that need to be run, and send them out on the mapreduce.

If you execute this task thousands of times a day (every minute), it may start getting expensive because you're issuing many queries.  Note that if most of those queries return nothing, the cost is still minimal.

The other option is to store your tasks in memory rather than in the datastore, that's where you'd want to start using backends.  But backends are expensive to maintain.  Look into using Google Compute Engine, which gives much cheaper VMs.

EDIT:

If you go the cron/datastore route, you'd store a new entity whenever a user wants to send a deferred message.  Most importantly, it'd have a queryable timestamp for when the message should be sent, probably rounded to the nearest minute or the nearest 5 minutes, whatever you decide your granularity should be.

You would then have a cron job that runs at the set interval, say every minute.  On each run it would build a query for all the cron jobs it needs to send for the given minute.

If you really do have hundreds of thousands of messages to send each minute, you're not going to want to do it from the cron task.  You'd want the cron task to spawn a mapreduce job that will fan out the query and spawn tasks to send your messages.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks!  The model I'm looking at is where tasks come in continuously and are processed continuously (with a one-day lag), so I assume the cron + mapreduce solution wouldn't work?

Comment: Depends on your granularity.  If you're ok with going every 5 minutes, that'll only be 288 calls a day, which isn't bad.  Going to every minute would be 1440.  I wouldn't go anything like a cron task per second... at that point tasks will easily start before the previous completed.

Comment: Doesn't this run into the same problem as before?  Instead of figuring out how to queue jobs for a day, you now have to queue them for 5 minutes.

Comment: If you're ok with sending out messages at 5 minute intervals, this will work.  IF you need to be accurate to the second, then you probably want to use a server on Compute Engine.

Comment: I mean, GAE only gives you the ability to respond to requests, so how can you store messages for the 5 minutes it takes to spawn the next cron task, without using something silly like [time.sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254678/app-engine-is-time-sleep-counting-towards-my-quotas)?