# App Engine Python, Standard Environment, using time.sleep

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-python

I read that using time.sleep counts against some CPU quota. I never heard of such a quota before or could find anything in the docs. Can someone enlighten me please?
EDIT: Since the other questions are 8 years old and I couldnt find anything in the docs or in the Google Cloud Console (at IAM & admin, Quota), I suspect the Quota is obsolete now and a updated clarification is in order IMO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App Engine: Is time.sleep() counting towards my quotas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254678/app-engine-is-time-sleep-counting-towards-my-quotas)

Comment: Well, this question is 8years old, I suspect the CPU quota is obsolete now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure what you mean by CPU "quota", but sleeping a thread would not stop the instance which will still be counted in your instance uptime and thus will be charged. You can see how usage is calculated for app engine [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing).

Comment: yeah sure, but in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254678/app-engine-is-time-sleep-counting-towards-my-quotas its stated that there is some kind of CPU quota. Whats is up with that? I suspect its obsolete since this thread is 8 years old

Comment: It's before even my time, what they are talking about in that thread is no longer true.